# What dose 1.-1 mean in all shader language

Tags: glsl, shader, render, hlsl, cg

I saw glsl code like this:

```
vec3 color = vec3(.0);
float var = 0;
color += 1.-step(0.2,var);
```

What does **`color += 1.-step(0.2,var)`** mean, I found it also work for cg language.And it has other form:
`1.-1`, `1.-0`, etc

Is `.-` a operator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `.-` operator. `1.` is a floating point literal (`1.0`). So `1.-step(0.2,var)` is exactly the same as `1.0 - step(0.2,var)`. `.0` is the same as `0.0`.

See [OpenGL Shading Language 4.60 Specification- 4.1.4. Floats](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.html#floats)

Answer (score 1):

`1.` is called a *floating-point constant* (see *section 4.1.4 Floats* of the GLSL specification). `-` is called the *arithmetic binary subtract operator* (see *section 5.9 Expressions* of the GLSL specification).

Answer (score 0):

The `.` is part of the constant `1.` making it a floating point constant rather than an integer constant.  The `-` is just a subtract operator.

This is mostly only relevant in GLSL which does not allow mixing integer and floating point values in expressions (no implicit conversions) -- you need an explicit cast.  So an expresion like `1.-step(0.2,var)` is a subtract, where as `1-step(0.2,var)` would be a type error (trying to subtract a floating point value from and integer.

An expression like `1.-0` would similarly be a type error.

Comment: *"`1-step(0.2,var)` would be a type error"* - That depends on the glsl version. Most recent version do automatically conversions.